# counting 2D list in python

Tags: python

my 2D list just like:

```
log = [[time1, 'aaa', '123.123.123.123'], [time2, 'def', '123.123.123.123'], [time3, 'aaa', '123.123.123.123'], [time4, 'bbb', '123.123.123.123'], [time5, 'bbb', '123.123.123.123']]
```

what I want is, the output below by using for loop:

```
aaa: 2
def: 1
bbb: 2
```

how can I count the specific col in a 2D list by loop?

Comment: Do you know what is a counter in python? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/counters-in-python

Answer (score 1):

This here should give you the solution

```
from collections import Counter

for k, v in Counter([a[1] for a in log]).items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

Output:

```
aaa: 2
def: 1
bbb: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try with the regular `dict`:

```
log = [[time1, 'aaa', '123.123.123.123'], [time2, 'def', '123.123.123.123'], [time3, 'aaa', '123.123.123.123'], [time4, 'bbb', '123.123.123.123'], [time5, 'bbb', '123.123.123.123']]

#Keep track of the counts in the dictionary
counter = dict()

for item in log:
    key = item[1]
    counter[key] = counter.get(key, 0) + 1 #If the key doesn't exist, initialize its count to 0 

print(counter)
```

This would give you the expected output as:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code should meet your requirements :

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
Counter(np.array(log)[:,1])
```

Comment: it can show the exact result, but how can I add more extra code during counting? this is the reason why I ask for a for loop solution.

Comment: Do you mean you have specific treatment to do while counting ? Is it impossible for you to do it after counting ? I can't see what kind of treatment couldn't be do after counting.

Comment: as you can there is a record about time, I want to check the time delta[0] between those  duplicated col[1]

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import Counter

ele = [r[1] for r in log]
ele_counts = Counter(ele)
print(dict(ele_counts))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'aaa': 2, 'def': 1, 'bbb': 2}
```

Comment: Counter is a dict. There is no need to pack this again in a dict.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
log = [[time1, 'aaa', '123.123.123.123'], [time2, 'def', '123.123.123.123'], [time3, 'aaa', '123.123.123.123'], [time4, 'bbb', '123.123.123.123'], [time5, 'bbb', '123.123.123.123']]
ans = [0,0,0]
for x in log:
  if x[1] == 'aaa':
    ans[0] += 1
  elif x[1] == 'def':
    ans[1] += 1
  else:
    ans[2] += 1

print(f'aaa: {ans[0]}\ndef: {ans[1]}\nbbb: {ans[2]}')
```

you must define time1 ~ time5 before check the code